# RegEx works online in RegexR but fails to initialise on iOS in NSRegularExpression

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I have a regex designed to extract the git URL from a CocoaPods definition.

The input text is as follows:

```
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'dev'
```

The regex is as follows:

```
(?<=('Alamofire'.*:git => '))[A-Za-z:/\.]+(?=('{1}))
```

This regex works correctly on RegexR, see [here](https://regexr.com/49o3h), however when trying to initialise `NSRegularExpression` with it, a error is thrown with code 2048 saying the pattern is invalid. Usually this is due to a lack of escapes but there are none here. I can't work out what the problem is even after trawling the ICU regex docs which is the engine iOS uses.

Any ideas would be well received, TIA.

Comment: Your lookbehind contains `.*`. You can't have patterns quantified with `*` or `+` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use patterns of unknown length in lookbehind patterns with ICU regular expressions. Your pattern contains `.*` in the lookbehind, so it is an invalid [ICU regexp](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) (see the *length of possible strings matched by the look-behind pattern must not be unbounded (no `*` or `+` operators.)* ICU lookbehind documentation part).

There are two ways:

- Replace `.*` with `.{0,x}` where `x` is the max number of chars you expect to separate the left-hand pattern from the right-hand pattern, ICU regex lookbehinds allow the *limiting* (or *interval*,  *range*) quantifier, that is why they are also called "constrained-width")
- Re-vamp your pattern to use a consuming pattern instead of lookarounds, wrap the part you need to extract with capturing parentheses and modify your code to grab Group 1 value.

Here is Approach 2, which is recommended:

```
let str = "pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'dev'"
let rng = NSRange(location: 0, length: str.utf16.count)
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "'Alamofire'.*:git\\s*=>\\s*'([^']+)'")
let matches = regex.matches(in: str, options: [], range: rng)
let group1 = String(str[Range(matches[0].range(at: 1), in: str)!])
print(group1) // => https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C1WMM3/1), the green highlighted substring is the value you get in Group 1.

Pattern details:

- `'Alamofire'` - a literal string
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (replace with `.*?` to match as few as possible)
- `:git` - a literal substring
- `\s*=>\s*`  - a `=>` substring wrapped with 0+ whitespaces
- `'([^']+)'` - `'`, then a capturing group #1 matching 1+ chars other than `'` and then a `'` char.

Answer (score 1):

The look-behind assertion in `NSRegularExpression` is limited and does not support the `*` or `+` operators in it:

i.e. the `.*` part in `(?<=('Alamofire'.*:git => '))`

> (?<= ... )
>
> Look-behind assertion. True if the parenthesized pattern matches text
>   preceding the current input position, with the last character of the
>   match being the input character just before the current position. Does
>   not alter the input position. The length of possible strings matched
>   by the look-behind pattern must not be unbounded (no * or +
>   operators.)
>
> <sub>Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression</sub>

You just want the url so simply pattern match only that part and no need for the look-behind assertion in the first place.